# Creating an printing an object that stores strings and integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, java.util.scanner

I have the following problem. Five classes are interacting with each other. Two of theme are doing fine. But with the creating of an Object of one class (Ticket) in my main class Event (getting user input from another class (UserInput), an processing this in the costructor) i have now problem to display the results.

Main class Event with main methode

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Event {

    
    private static String artistName;
    private static int artistSalary;
    private Language language;
    private static ArrayList<String> trackList;
    private InputReader inputReader;
    private Ticket ticket;
    private int amountOfTicketCategories;
    private static Object[] ticketList;
    private static int index;
    
    
    
    public Event() {
        
    }
    
    public Event(Artist artist, Ticket ticket) {
        artistName = artist.getArtistName();
        artistSalary = artist.getArtistSalary();
        trackList = artist.getArrayList();
        for (index = 0; index < amountOfTicketCategories; index++) {
        ticketList[index] = ticket.getTicket();
        ticketList[index].toString();
        }
    }
    
    public void chooseWhatToDefine() {
        language = new Language();
        language.whatToSpecify();
    }


    public void setTicketPrice(String ticketCategory, int ticketPrice) {
    
    }
    
    public void displayArtist(String artistName, int artistSalary) {
        language = new Language();
        language.displayArtistAndSalary(artistName, artistSalary);
    }
    
    public void displayTracklist(ArrayList<String> trackList) {
        language = new Language();
        language.displayTrackList(trackList);
    }
    
    public void displayTickets(Object[] ticketList) {
        language = new Language();
        language.displayTicket(ticketList);
    }           
                        
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Event event1 = new Event(new Artist(), new Ticket());
    
        event1.displayArtist(artistName, artistSalary);
        event1.displayTracklist(trackList);
        event1.displayTickets(ticketList);
    
}
}
```

Ticket class with constructor that initalize the class with the user input comming from the InputReader class, and creates an object of Strings and Integers.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ticket {

    
    private static String ticketCategory;
    private static int ticketAmount;
    private static int ticketPrice;
    private InputReader inputReader;
    private int amountOfTicketCategories;
    private int index;
    private Ticket[] ticketList;
    
    public Ticket(String ticketCategory,int ticketAmount,int ticketPrice) {
        
    }
    
    public Ticket() {
    inputReader = new InputReader();
    inputReader.specifyTicketCategories();
    ticketList = new Ticket[amountOfTicketCategories];
    for (index = 0; index < amountOfTicketCategories; index++) {
    inputReader.specifyTicket(ticketCategory, ticketAmount, ticketPrice);
    ticketList[index] = new Ticket(ticketCategory, ticketAmount, ticketPrice);
    
    
}
    }
    
public String toString() {
    return("TicketCategory: " + ticketCategory + "Amount of Tickets: " + ticketAmount + "Ticket Price: " +ticketPrice);
}

public Object getTicket() {
    return ticketList[index];
}

public int getAmountOfTicketCategories() {
    amountOfTicketCategories = inputReader.specifyTicketCategories();
    return amountOfTicketCategories;

    
    
}
}
```

InptReader class that processes the user input:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputReader {

    private  Scanner sc;
    private  Language language;
    private  ArrayList <String> tracks;
    
    
    
    
    
    public InputReader() {
        tracks = new ArrayList<String>();
        language = new Language();
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        

    }

    public int specifyTicketCategories() {
        language.defineAmountOfTicketCategories();
        return sc.nextInt();
    
        
    }
    
    public void specifyTicket(String ticketCategory, int ticketAmount, int ticketPrice) {
        language.specifyTicketCategory();
        ticketCategory = sc.next();
        language.specifyTicketAmount();
        ticketAmount = sc.nextInt();
        language.specifyTicketPrice();
        ticketPrice = sc.nextInt();
        
    }
    
    public int amountOfTickets() {
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    public int ticketPrice() {
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    
    public String readName() {
        language.specifyArtist();
        return sc.nextLine();

    }

    public int readInteger() {
        language.specifyArtistSalary();
        return sc.nextInt();

    }

    public void addTitle() {
        int anzahlSongs = 3;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < anzahlSongs) {
            language.specifyTrackList();
            tracks.add(sc.nextLine());
            index++;
        }
    

}
    public  ArrayList<String> getArray() {
        return tracks;
    }

}
```

Language class that consists of the language statements

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Language {
    
    public Language () {
    
        
    }

    public void whatToSpecify() {
        System.out.println("What would you like to specify fist? For Artist press 1, for Ticket press 2");
    }
    
    public void specifyArtist() {
    System.out.println("Who is the artist? ");
}


public void specifyArtistSalary() {
    System.out.println("How much does the artist earn? ");
}

public void displayTicket(Object[] ticketList) {
    System.out.println("Ticketlist: " + ticketList);
}
    
public void displayArtistAndSalary(String artistName, int artistSalary) {
    System.out.println("Artist: " + artistName + " " + "Salary: " + artistSalary);
}

public void displayTrackList(ArrayList<String> trackList) {
    System.out.println("Tracklist: " + trackList);
}

public void specifyTicketCategory() {
    System.out.println("What is the ticket category? ");
}

public void specifyTicketAmount() {
    System.out.println("What ist the amount of tickets? ");
}

public void specifyTicketPrice() {
    System.out.println("What is the price for your ticket?");
}

public void specifyTrackList() {
    System.out.println("Add title: ");
}

public void defineAmountOfTicketCategories() {
    System.out.println("How many ticket categories you like to set up?");
}

public void line() {
    System.out.println("***********************************");
}

}
```

Artist class that that has creates an instance of an artist in the main class (same idea as for ticket) but with other variables and parameters.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Artist {

    private int artistSalary;
    private String artistName;
    private InputReader inputReader;
    ArrayList <String> trackList;
    
    
    

    public Artist() {
        
        
        inputReader = new InputReader();
        artistName =    inputReader.readName();
        artistSalary = inputReader.readInteger();
        inputReader.addTitle();
        trackList = inputReader.getArray();
        trackList.remove(2);
        
            
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;

    }

    public int getArtistSalary() {
        return artistSalary;
    }

                
    
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
        return trackList;
    }

}
```

Output in the console:
Add title:
Hello
Add title:
Hello
How many ticket categories you like to set up?
5
Artist: David Salary: 5000
Tracklist: [, Hello]
Ticketlist: null

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the Ticket class's constructor, you use the other constructor (The one with the 3 arguments), which has an empty body.

`ticketList[index] = new Ticket(ticketCategory, ticketAmount, ticketPrice);`

```
public Ticket(String ticketCategory,int ticketAmount,int ticketPrice) {
    //this is empty
}
```

That means you're creating an object with.. nothing in it (null variables).

Try this:

```
public Ticket(String ticketCategory,int ticketAmount,int ticketPrice) {
    this.ticketCategory = ticketCategory;
    this.ticketAmount = ticketAmount;
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
}
```

Then, your getTicket method is wrong. You never define the "index" integer in your Ticket class.

```
public Object getTicket() {
    return ticketList[index];
}
```

Where "index" is undefined.

The ticketList should not be in the Ticket class => each time you create a Ticket instance, it will probably not be the same as the previous one.

Comment: thank you very much. the problem with the ticketList ist that it uses InputReader and  I create a new instance of TicketReader in my constructor. thats why i can not create an new input reader object in the event class i guess.

Comment: There are a lot of problems, I think you can do that in a better way.
Tips : if you want to create a list of objects, don't put the list inside the object itself, but in an other class (for example DataManager with fields like ticketList, trackList, artist and so on, with getters and setters).
Then, you can create one instance of this class in your main method, when you run the code.

Comment: if i am doing this: `public void specifyTicketCategories(int amountOfTicketCategories) {
  language.defineAmountOfTicketCategories();
  amountOfTicketCategories = sc.nextInt();` , creating a setter and  getter in the Data manager class `public void setAmountOfTicketCategories(int amountOfTicketCategories) {
inputReader.specifyTicketCategories(amountOfTicketCategories);
 
 
}
public int getAmountOfTicketCategories(int amountOfTicketCategories) {
 return amountOfTicketCategories;
}`  ist this correct?